# How does the let keyword work in this code?

Tags: javascript

I'm new to programming and struggling with this code.

I know that "let" is block scoped, but how does the setTimeout access the "i" variable when its outside its sccope. I would really appreciate if someone could explain the code to me step by step.

```
      for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
     console.log(i);
      setTimeout(function () {
      console.log('the number is ' + i);
      }, 1000);

      }
```

Comment: It works just like var does

Comment: The `i` isn’t outside the setTimeout scope. The setTimeout is inside the same block.

Comment: @NicholasTower for this very basic demonstrations it relates better to beginners to give them something they can relate to. There's always nuance.